# Help visualizing this quotient space

Tags: general-topology

I'm having a lot of trouble visualizing (or getting some basic properties) of this quotient space.

Consider $\mathbb R^2$ with the next equivalence relationship:
$$(x,y)\sim(x+n,e^ny)\qquad n\in\mathbb Z$$

Verifying that that relation is actually an equivalence relation is easy. So I want to consider the quotient topological space of $\mathbb R^2$ with that.

I'm seeing we are identifying parallel lines of constant $x$, but like stretching them exponentially, so some kind of weird cylinder?

Could anyone give some basic insight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quotient space $q:\Bbb R^2\to Y$ is just an infinite cylinder $S^1\times\Bbb R$. If you look at the map $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ which sends $(x,y)\to (x,e^x y)$, it has an inverse $g$ which sends $(x,y)\mapsto (x,e^{-x}y)$. Further, the images of $f(x,y)$ and $f(x+n,y)$ are identified by your relation, while the points $g(x,y)$ and $g(x+n,e^n y)$ are identified by the relation $(x,y)\sim (x+n,y)$. Now this relation produces an infinite cylinder, so we have induced maps $\tilde f:S^1\times\Bbb R\to Y$ and $\tilde g:Y\to S^1\times\Bbb R$, and these maps are inverse to each other.

Hence the quotient space $Y$ is just an infinite cylinder.

Now this tells you how the resulting space looks like. If you want to visualize how it is obtained from the domain, you can think of wrapping the plane around a cylinder, but the line $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ is compressed by the factor $e$ before it is glued to $\{x-1\}\times\Bbb R$.

Comment: I was seeing that cylinder, just wanted to be able to visualize that "wrapping and stretching" a little bit better.